# Facebook получение данных о пользователе при авторизаций

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-api

Интересует вот такой вопрос: Как при авторизаций через Facebook получить данные о пользователе (Public Profile) или аватарку? Интересует реализация на ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6.

Вот отрезок кода из файла *Startup.cs*:

```
services.Configure<FacebookAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                options.Scope.Add("public_profile");
            });

/* ....... */

app.UseFacebookAuthentication();
```

При авторизации получаю Claim которы содержит только полное имя (Full Name).

**Но как получить например аватарку или Email пользователя?**

**Нужно использовать OAuth?**

**Если да то как?**

Comment: Аватарка получается легко: `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_FACEBOOK_UID/picture?type=square&height=100&width=100` Чтобы мыло получить надо разрешения у юзера запрашивать, но пользователь может их не дать и мыло вы не получите. Как это на asp.net делается не знаю

Comment: Судя по параметрам, там внутри уже используется OAuth2. Надо документацию к классу аутентификации смотреть. Если им то можно решить, то там написано, как.